# Text won't appear in TextView

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am making a **Navigation Drawer** in my Android app. The Navigation Drawer has an **Header** which includes a **Account Icon** and a **Text View**. But when I run the App, I can no longer see the Icon or the TextView.

This is what I have been getting,

[image]

Here is my code for my navigation drawer **`activity_admin.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.vishistvarugeese.ongc_app.AdminActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            app:headerLayout="@layout/admin_nav_header" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:menu="@menu/admin_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:theme="@style/menu_style">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

This is the code for my navigation header, **`admin_nav_header.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/headernav"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_48dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/navUserName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I was trying to do

[image]

Can someone please help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove theme and other property from NavigationView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/homeDrawerColor"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/admin_nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/admin_menu" />
```

If not work then give a direct string to check any problem in string.xml or not...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked :D Why wouldn't it work with the theme?

Comment: I think theme overlap text & image color as headernav.